# how to find keys in container.Map without brackets if keys are integers?

Tags: matlab, dictionary, containers

```
t=containers.Map('KeyType','int32', 'ValueType','any');
t(1)=2;
t(4)=5;

keys=keys(t);
keys = 

    [1]    [3]
```

I need that keys alone, just 1 3

Comment: it's as simple as: `cell2mat(keys)`

Comment: @Amro - oops.  I didn't see your comment.  I wouldn't have posted if I saw this.  Should I delete my answer and let you post?

Comment: no that's ok. Sometimes I'm too lazy to write a complete post, especially when the answer is a single line of code :)

Answer (score 0):

`keys` returns the keys in a cell array.  If you want to eliminate the cell array format all together and just return the keys as a matrix, just use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

```
keys = cell2mat(keys);
```

With your example, we get:

```
keys = 

1        4
```

NB: You have a slight typo in your code.  You created a `containers.Map()` with keys of `1` and `4`, but you showed the output as `1`, and `3`.